# SVG elements events

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a div with multiple SVG elements acting as buttons, The div and its elements are all added after the page loads and the user does some staff.
I want to add events to the SVG elements, so using event delegation, I get the event then inspect its target.
The problem is when I try this everything works just fine. but when I click on the element:

 `e.target` property sometimes returns the SVG element and other times returns a path element.
I came up with a workaround to this using 2 conditions in my event handler for each button ,along with check for the parent or element id, and It worked but I want to know why this is happening.
The best thing I could come up with is that the path represents the borders of the icons but I am not sure.

If I used an `<i>` tag for my icons, will I have the same issue?
EDIT:

```
var secondCondition = (e.target.tagName === 'path' && e.target.parentElement.id === 'icon-circle-with-minus');
if (e.target.matches('.servingsDecrease *, .servingsDecrease') || secondCondition) {
     console.log('dec');
}
```

this code works fine.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: I just added a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

> e.target property sometimes returns the SVG element and other times returns a path element.

That is exactly how it is meant to work. `e.target` represents the element which »received« the event and in most cases that is some nested child of the element, to which the event listener is attached to.

Have a look [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) for more detailed information about event bubbling/capturing to get an understanding how such events work.

Basically you only need to add one event listener to the entire page like that:

```
window.addEventListener('click', e => console.log(e.target));
```

to catch **every** click on the page. going from there you need a way to delegate the event to an appropriate handler. I often found myself happy with a solution like that:

**sample HTML**

```
<div class="btns">
  <div data-click-handler="btn">
    <span>
      <p>some sample content</p>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div data-click-handler="btn2">
   <ul>
    <li>…</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const handlers = {
  btn: e => alert('btn clicked'),
  btn2: e => alert('btn2 clicked')
}

window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let 
    c = e.target,
    //that could be an array as well
    //if you want all the handlers on
    //»way upwards« to be called
    handler = null
  ;

  //as long as there is a Node
  while (c && c.hasAttribute) {
    //check if it should listen to events
    if (c.hasAttribute('data-click-handler')) {
      //get the handler if it exists
      let key = c.getAttribute('data-click-handler');
      if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        handler = handlers[key];
        //break the loop to keep the reference to
        //»desired target«
        break;
      }
    }
    //go upwards in the tree
    c = c.parentNode;
  }

  //finally call the handler, if any
  if (handler !== null) handler(c);
});
```

That is just an illustration/outline of a way to implement event delegation, to overcome the need to register a dedicated event handler for each element to should trigger some code on events. In case you have whole bunch of elements that needs to respond to certain events, you might need such a technique to overcome performance issues.

Basically there are plenty of ways to do such a thing, another using the `<element>.matches() API` is described [here](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Comment: The last edit I added a code snippet that allow me to successfully catch the event, I am asking for the reason why I am sometimes getting `path` and other times getting `svg` elements.
A side note on your code, I think using closest() method will be more convenient.
`e.target.closest('div[data-click-handler]')`

Comment: The `target` of an event is the node that received the event, and must necessarily be the one the event was registered to. Since an Inline SVG is just a regular part of the DOM, `<path>` elements become the target, if you click on them. I don't think that is important to discus the  various methods to get the »closest« element, since it just important to search the DOM tree »upwards«.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `currentTarget` property of the event instead of the `target`. The `currentTarget` is the element the event is attached to. Run the snippet below and click on the different elements to see it in action.

I realize this may not be helpful--it's a little hard to discern wjen and where the event handlers are added from your post. If it's not, let me know and I'll remove this answer.

```js
function clickHandler(e){
  console.log('target: ', e.target.tagName);
  console.log('currentTarget: ',e.currentTarget.tagName);
}
```

```html
<svg width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 80 80" style="background:green;" onclick="clickHandler(event)">
  <path d="M0,0 L20,0 L20,20 L0,20 Z" fill="red"/>
  <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="15" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```